# One-tail versus two-tail z-score

Tags: sample-size

In calculating minimum sample size one must specify, inter alia, z-score. I am estimating a min sample size for an accuracy rate. As I only care if the accuracy rate is lower (happy if it is higher) then shouldn't I employ a one-tail z-score?

has anyone encountered literature / internet on that subject?

Answer (score 0):

If the intent of your study is to do a one-sided test of a hypothesis, then as you said, the `z-value` you use in calculating your sample size should be a one-tail `z-value` (i.e., $z_{\alpha}$ not $z_{\alpha/2}$. [This web page](http://www.andrews.edu/~calkins/math/edrm611/edrm11.htm) and [this PDF file](http://gchang.people.ysu.edu/class/s5817/L/L5817_1_2_PowerSampleSize_n.pdf) lightly touch on this issue.

Comment: Thank you. Ceteris paribus a one-tailed test would deliver a lower z-score than a two-tail test. Thus also a lower minimum sample size. My concern is whether any ensuing lower finite population correction (fpc)  is appropriate. I guess once one has estimated a sample size then the flow-on effects onto the fpc are appropriate / correct.

Comment: If your question is about when it is accepted to use a one-sided test, I can recommend this site with a few enlightening examples: https://statisticsbyjim.com/hypothesis-testing/use-one-tailed-tests/